# MS Access SQL - Left Join (or sub-query?) most recent related record

Tags: query, ms-access

Hello Database Administrators.

Thank you so much for your help with this issue. It blows my mind that something so simple can be so complicated.

I have an MS Access database with two tables.

The first is called Lead. It contains a primary key field ("LeadID"), and then Firstname, Lastname, etc.

The second is called Activity. It contains various fields like ActivityID (primary key), Summary, ActivityDate (a datetime stamp), Status, and LeadID, which is the foreign key for Lead. Lead and Activity, thus, have a one-to-many relationship.

For two days now, I have been trying to create a query that joins each record in Lead with its most recent Activity record.

I've tried using a subquery.

I've tried a LEFT JOIN.

I got excited when I saw that I can achieve this with an OUTER APPLY, but this, apparently, is not supported in MS Access.

I cannot believe that such an obvious use case would be so difficult to implement.

Am I thinking about this wrong?

Please advise how I can achieve this query.

Thank you so much.

EDIT:

So, I tried the query that Ergest Basha provided below. After getting various syntax errors, I did some research, and added parentheses.

This is as far as I've got:

```
FROM  (Lead l 
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT  LeadID,
                    MAX(ActivityDate) latest_ActivityDate
             FROM   Activity
             GROUP BY LeadID
           ) MaxDates ON (l.LeadID = MaxDates.LeadID)) 
INNER JOIN Activity a ON  (MaxDates.LeadID = a.LeadID AND MaxDates.latest_ActivityDate = a.ActivityDate)
```

Now, when I try to run this, Access gives me an error saying "JOIN expression not supported".

What am I doing wrong?